# How to show an image in Jasper Reports using Struts plugin

Tags: image, struts, jasper-reports

I am using Struts 2.2.1 and Jasper 2.2.1 plugin with Jasper 4.5.0. and running my webapp on jboss 5.1

I am trying to show my logo.png on the title of the report however i cant seem to show it.

I have tried various solutions posted on the web. But cant seem to get it working.

In the jrxml file I have:

```
   <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{LOGO_OPEN}"]]></imageExpression>
```

And in my action class i have:

```
final String path ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
final String imageUrl = path + "images/graphics/header.png";
reportParams.put("LOGO_OPEN", imageUrl);
```

The Struts.xml file has in its action the following parameters:

```
<result name="success" type="jasper">
    <param name="location">/jasper/itineraryDetails.jasper</param>
    <param name="dataSource">itineraryDetailsList</param>
    <param name="format">PDF</param>
    <param name="reportParameters">reportParams</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="tripDetails.pdf"</param>
  </result>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is instead of passing in the String to the path of the image, is pass in the actual Image. Try to change your parameter to:

```
<parameter name="LOGO_OPEN" class="java.lang.Object"/>
```

and your image expression to:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{LOGO_OPEN}]]></imageExpression>
```

and update the code in your action class to:

```
final String path ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
final String imageUrl = path + "images/graphics/header.png";
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imageUrl);
reportParams.put("LOGO_OPEN", image.getImage());
```